Generalised Laplace/Gauss transform of $\frac{\exp(-ax)}{x}$
Let $a>0$ be a constant and suppose $x\in\mathbb R_+$, how to prove：
$\frac{\exp(-ax)}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2t^2-\frac{a^2}{4t^2})dt$ ?
This seems like the generalised Laplace/Gauss transform of $\frac{\exp(-ax)}{x}$ but I couldn't prove it.

Consider reworking your question. You’re asking for an integral evaluation, there’s no need to be ‘Given a function $f$ …’

First, observe that
$$
x^2 t^2 + \frac{a^2}{4t^2} = \frac{a x}{2}\left(
\frac{2x}{a} t^2 + \frac{a}{2x} t^{-2}
\right).
$$
With $s = t\sqrt{\frac{2 x}{a}}$ the integral can be written as
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi x}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s^2 + s^{-2}\right)\right\}d s.
$$
As $s^2 + s^{-2} = \left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2 + 2$, it can be simplified further to
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi x}} e^{-ax}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s = 
2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi x}} e^{-ax}
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s.
$$
Let's focus on the latter integral only. With $r = s^{-1}$ and $ds = -r^{-2} dr$,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s = 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(r^{-1} - r\right)^2\right\} r^{-2} d r,
$$
so with $y = s - s^{-1}$
$$
2 \int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s = \\ =
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s + \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(r^{-1} - r\right)^2\right\} r^{-2} d r = \\ =
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 + s^{-2}\right) \exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d s = 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}\left(s - s^{-1}\right)^2\right\}d \left(s - s^{-1}\right) = \\ =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\frac{a x}{2}y^2\right\}d y = \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{a x}}
$$
as it's the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda y^2} dy = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$.
Hence, the initial integral is equal to
$$
2 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi x}} \cdot e^{-ax} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{a x}} = \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}
$$
as required.
